# Can I use SonarQube 6.7 LTS Community version with commercial plugins?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I'm confused about SonrQube usage. According to the [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR)

> SonarQube® software (previously called Sonar) is an open source quality management platform

At the same time SonarSource sells some [subscription plans](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/) and some [commercial plug-ins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library).

My first question is: can we use commercial plugins with the open source SonarQube Community version?

Another question is: when I installed the Community version 6.7 LTS I am not able to find any license option under administration?  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

As you pointed out, there is a free and open source edition, named **Community Edition**.

Some plugins and features are not in the **Community Edition** (and they are not OSS), however the platform (SonarQube) is the same, but you will have to upgrade to **Developer Edition** or **Enterprise Edition** (and if you want high availability to the **DataCenter Edition**) to be able to use the features.

When you have installed commercial edition, the licence options will appear in the Administration page.

*Disclosure : I'm working for SonarSource.*

Comment: Is there any limitation on the number of users when I have a Community Edition? Can you point me to any license agreement which states this information?

Comment: There is no limitation on the number of users for the Community Edition. You can find the licence (LGPL 3.0) on https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube (end of the page) and on https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/license/

Comment: @EricHartmann What is the difference between the community edition and community edition LTS

Comment: @VijenderKumar The LTS version is released once a year and blocker issues are backported to this version. So it's an older version that had been hardened and we have backported some fixes.

Comment: @EricHartmann Can we use the Enterprise edition 'as' Community Edition? i.e. by not supplyingany license, can one still use the Community features, or is there a point to uninstalling and installing the CE ?